# How can solve this problem because I cannot open iOS simulator when I usd flutter development

Tags: ios, flutter

How can solve this problem because I cannot open iOS simulator when I usd flutter development.

When I need to open ios simulator, it was show me error... but before it's working I don't know why now was error.

```
Error (Xcode): unable to read property list from file: /Users/Stanley/Desktop/yomate/ios/Runner/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
```

This is my Info.plist

Who knows where has problems?

Did I do modify something or delete something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Yomate</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>yomate</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Photo Library Usage</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Mic Usage</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Privacy Camera Usage</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try delete `<true/>` at the bottom of your info.plist file. let me know if it's work

```
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
  <true/> // delete this line
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I'd deleted it, but got this information `Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:50182/VbUvSY6Rbzc=/ws
Lost connection to device.
`
Still cannot running

Comment: try running it on iOS simulator or other devic. if you are using real device to debug, make sure the usb cable is not disconnected.